# Скрипт для Гугл Таблиц (Spreadsheets). Как при изменении в строке перенести значение по условию?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Есть скрипт, который при любом изменении в отслеживаемом столбце ставит дату в строке, где это изменение произошло.

```html
    function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
var idRow = e.range.getRow();
if ( idCol == 6 && sheet.getName() =='Распиловка / присадка' ) {

var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

sheet.getRange(idRow, 7).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 8).setValue(varnow);

}
//  if ( idCol == 2 && sheet.getName() =='Распиловка / присадка' ) {
//  var vartoday = getDate();
//var varnow = getTime();
//
//sheet.getRange(idRow, 4).setValue( vartoday );
//sheet.getRange(idRow, 5).setValue(varnow);
//
//}

  if ( idCol == 2 && sheet.getName() =='Шлифовка / покраска' ) {
  var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

sheet.getRange(idRow, 4).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 5).setValue(varnow);

}
    
if ( idCol == 6 && sheet.getName() =='Шлифовка / покраска' ) {

var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

sheet.getRange(idRow, 7).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 8).setValue(varnow);    
    
    
}

function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
}

function getTime() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'HH:mm');
}
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вставку даты с дополнительным условием? Т.е. в отслеживаемом столбце возникло изменение, но, допустим, значение это = "В работе". В этом случае дата в измененную строку не вставляется. Но как только происходит ещё одно изменение в отслеживаемом столбце, но значение = "Готов" - тогда в измененной строке проставляется дата.

Сама таблица: http://joxi.ru/EA4BkYotwqgk3m

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, понял.
Надо было просто прописать

```html
}
    
  if ( idCol == 6 && sheet.getName() =='Шлифовка / покраска' && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() == "Готов" ) {
```

и всё заработало.